# How to iterate, so to add the unique values in dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

This is the code in which I tried to get the data from one website using the requests and saved in dictionary called table but when I tried to iterate through those values and saved them in the list , I faced with below error, any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list1 = []
table = {}

r = requests.get("https://www.century21.com/real-estate/rock-springs-wy/LCWYROCKSPRINGS/?k=1")
content =  r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')

all = soup.find_all('div',{"class":"property-card-primary-info"})
for item in all:
    print(item.find('a',{"class":"listing-price"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))
    table['address'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-address"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    table['city'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-city"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    table['beds'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-beds"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    table['baths'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-baths"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    try:
        table['half-baths'] = item.find("div",{"class":"property-half-baths"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
    except:
        table['half-baths'] = None
    try:
        table['property sq.ft.'] = item.find("div",{"class":"property-sqft"}).text.replace('  ','').replace("\n",'')
    except:
        table['property sq.ft.'] = None
    list1.append(table)
    list1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$325,000 
$249,000 
$390,000 
$274,900 
$208,000 
$169,000 
$127,500 
$990,999
```

I'm getting the unique values when I print price values , but when I append to the list all the values are replicated. Any help will means a lot.
**Question : how to get rid of this replication of data and get the corresponding values?**

```
[{'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '},
 {'address': ' 1129 Hilltop Drive',
  'city': 'Rock Springs WY 82901 ',
  'beds': '4 beds ',
  'baths': '5 baths ',
  'half-baths': '2 half baths ',
  'property sq.ft.': '10,300 sq. ft '}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in all:
    table ={} # important
    print(item.find('a',{"class":"listing-price"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))
    table['address'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-address"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    table['city'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-city"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    table['beds'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-beds"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    table['baths'] = item.find('div',{"class":"property-baths"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','') 
    try:
        table['half-baths'] = item.find("div",{"class":"property-half-baths"}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
    except:
        table['half-baths'] = None
    try:
        table['property sq.ft.'] = item.find("div",{"class":"property-sqft"}).text.replace('  ','').replace("\n",'')
    except:
        table['property sq.ft.'] = None
    list1.append(table)
```

`print(set(list1))` # print list outside the loop use set to remove dups

Comment: sir if I write outside the for, then only the last values from the dictionary-table is printed

Comment: ok just initialize table ={} inside for loop

Comment: I have updated the solution just try and verify

Comment: worked , when i added the table={} inside the for , i got the desired result. thank you.